# How do I get more Tickets?

Tags: dream-house-days

I was told that tickets are a pretty rare item in-game, and to be careful how I spent them.

I haven't really earned more since the beginning of the game. Wairobot will sell me them, but they cost real-world money, and I don't really want to spend real money.

Is there any other way to get tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get tickets:

**Play the game**
Save your game, quit, and re-launch it.  Re-load your save, and viola!  More tickets!

They are awarded at a rate of a ticket for every seven minutes, and you can claim up to a maximum of ten at once.  This time does not include being in menus, so you can't just idle the game and expect to receive them.

**Make friends**
Another way to get tickets is to add friends.  As I answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103325/20456):

> You get seven for originally registering (and having them accept) a new friend. After that, you get an extra ticket for every 40 minutes they play.

This time is combined across your friends; eg. if one plays 15 minutes, and another plays 30, you'll get a ticket, even though neither of them played 40 minutes.

**Win trophies**
Most trophies award you with a ticket or two when you hit their achievements.  Several trophies have their requirements available to be viewed, under Info --> Trophies, so you can see how close you are to getting another one, and its ticket rewards.

Answer (score 0):

I 've noticed when you upgrade accessories like hats, clothing, hair, ect... upgrade just one for each gender to about lv 3 or higher (of course you'll need enough tickets to do this) and when the people grow old and leave you'll get a 50/50 chance of getting free tickets.

Answer (score -1):

**Store**
After little bit in the game you are able to buy tickets in the store to.