# Why do I need friends?

Tags: dream-house-days

This game gives you the option to make friends by entering the ID they used when starting the game.

Why do I want to make friends? How does that help me?

Comment: pfffft, who needs friends when you've got video games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding friends gives you tickets.  You get seven for originally registering (and having them accept) a new friend.  After that, you get an extra ticket for every 40 minutes they play.

Note: You can only have five friends, and I don't believe there's any punishment for unregistering a friend; theoretically, if you really wanted a lot of tickets, you could unfriend everybody, and friend other people.